# Are there some bargain accommodations along the land route from the southern tip of Albania to Thessaloniki?

Tags: budget, accommodation, routes, greece, hitchhiking

I'm currently in Sarandë, Albania but soon will head for Thessaloniki, Greece by hitchhiking.

I've tried the usual suspects like HostelBookers, HostelWorld, TripAdvisor, and WikiTravel, but none of them are great for finding accommodation along a route rather than at specific locations.

Basically I enjoy travelling on a tight budget and I know where to stay in Thessaloniki but would like to find some bargains along the way to break up the trip. I've become used to Balkan hostel prices. Below 10 euros per night is a bargain, 15 euros or above I might not stay, between is acceptable.

I have a sleeping bag [but not a tent though I'm on the lookout for one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/is-it-easier-and-or-cheaper-to-replace-my-lost-tent-in-albania-or-greece). I don't mind roughing it. [I won't really be able to couch surf since without a phone it's not easy to combine with hitchhiking.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/is-there-a-feasible-way-to-combine-hitchhiking-and-couch-surfing)

I'll cross the border at Konispol/Sagiada and head for the E90 which will take me to Thessaloniki. **Can you suggest some hostel or other non well known spot roughly along the route?**

Comment: I think that would be another cool business idea. A site that looks for hostels/hotels/camping places etc along a specific router rather than a city/place.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I can think if is using Google Maps. Enter your route and let it display on the map. Then go to the search box and enter for example hotel, hostel, camping, etc. You may have to try several keywords to find anything useful. After that, each result for that keyword is displayed on the map. Now you can check which of them are close enough to the route.

I [did it already](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hostel&hl=en&ll=40.040232,21.470032&spn=2.476999,5.984802&sll=40.157885,21.137695&sspn=2.472721,5.984802&vpsrc=6&t=m&doflg=ptk&hq=hostel&z=9) for hostels and the route Sarande to Thessaloniki.

Comment: I tried this too. Everything was way off the route, put in the wrong place by Google Maps!, or not at all a bargain )-: Except for [the campsite I found in Ioannina](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/whats-the-absolute-cheapest-accommodation-in-ioannina-greece) and I beached I free-camped at not far past the Albanian border.